# How to add additional MAC addresses to wireless MAC address filter in ZTE modem?

Tags: modem, mac-address, adsl

The Wireless MAC Address Filter in my ZTE modem allows me to input only 8 MAC addresses. How to add more than these 8 addresses ? My ZTE modem is ZXV10 W300 Series.

Answer (score 1):

How to filter MAC Address on ZTE ZXV10 W300 Modem

1. Open a browser e.g. Internet Explorer, Fire Fox, Chrome
2. Type http://192.168.1.1 in the address bar and hit Enter > type “admin” for username and “password” for password > OK
3. Click Interface Setup  > Wireless  and set up as follows:

3.1 Go to Wireless MAC Address Filter

3.2 Active > Default setting is Deactivated > To activate click Activated

3.3 Action > 2 options for selection

- Allow > allow the usage only the entered MAC Address
- Deny > not allow the usage of entered MAC Address

3.4 MAC Address # 1 – 8 > enter MAC Address to be filtered up to 8

3.5 After complete setup, click SAVE button

[image]

Comment: I think my question was about input more than the MAC 8 addresses, I mean how to do to let the modem accept for example up to 15 addresses ?